# Is there a risk in scarring your followers?

Tags: cultist-simulator

When one of your followers actively does something, for example doing the cult business (**TALK** + follower + **CULT**) or trying to overcome an obstacle during an expedition, there is a chance that they will become wounded and need to be healed (**TALK** +follower + **FUNDS**).

The wounds description says that three wounds of the same kind can kill a follower and that they can become sick (which I guess can produce another wound?). However, curing the wound gives you a scar, which has a positive effect, giving you +2 to an aspect (depending on the wound).

So is forcing followers to get scars a good tactic to increase their power or can they still die even after turning wounds to scars?

EDIT: I've misread the [wiki](https://cultistsimulator.gamepedia.com/Wound):

Comment: You should put the answer part as an answer instead of the question so other people can see this has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

I've misread the wiki:

> Wound are a representation of your followers' mortality. Each failure of cult business (of the types that may cause wounding) or exploration may cause your follower to become Wounded. Wounded followers are not available to use as followers and may only be cured by Talking with them and using 1 Funds. Followers that were not cured by the time the Season of Sickness rolls around will die. Cured Wounds turn into Scars.

> Three Scars of the same type will kill the follower.

A follower can have only one wound (which can kill him when he'll become sick), but up to 2 scars of the same type (3rd one will kill him/her). It is worth to point that there are only 3 wound types (giving +2 **EDGE**, **KNOCK** or **WINTER**), so the chance of accidentally getting 3 of the same types is quite high.

So it seems that doing it on purpose is a bit risky unless you have lots of followers to spare, however, a follower with 2 **KNOCK** from a scar gets so much more valuable, since 2 **KNOCK** enough for most of the summoning (actually, having any additional 2 points in another aspect is a huge bonus!).

So it might be worth to force a follower or two to get a scar for that extra 2 **KNOCK** points. Yes, there is a risk, but later on in the game you will be using mostly followers for summoning spirits and let the spirit do the hard, dangerous work.